# Android debugger failed to launch

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I run my project in Android 4.0. using Eclipse Helios editor with Java coding.Emulator is launched well and while I tried to debug the code then it showing error as "The Selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launch". How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dude Goto the preferences under Run/Debug > Launching

There's a section called "Launch Operation" and you needed to select:

Launch the selected resource or active editor. If no launchable: Launch the previously launched application.

or

Eclipse will by default attempt to run what it ran last time. So it would seem what you are trying to run is not working, and it has nothing to fall back on.
If it is a single file (i.e. the single file containing the main() method), right click it and choose run, then run as application.